# Need to find duplicates from an array in c++, and then put them in another array

Tags: c++, arrays, input, duplicates, output

this is my first post here and I would be very happy if you could help me.
The task is - Create an array from 6 input numbers, then put the duplicated numbers in another array and then output the array with the repeated numbers.

Do you have any ideas? I'm still a newbie and need some help. Thanks in advance guys !!

EDIT:
    I'm not sure if I'm on the right way, that's why I didn't post what I've done yet. But this is it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a[6];
int b[6];
int i,z;

for (i=0; i<6; i++){
cin>>a[i];
}
for (z=0; z<6; z++){
if (a[0]==a[1]) b[z]=a[0];
if (a[0]==a[2]) b[z]=a[0];
if (a[0]==a[3]) b[z]=a[0];
if (a[0]==a[4]) b[z]=a[0];
if (a[0]==a[5]) b[z]=a[0];
if (a[1]==a[2]) b[z]=a[1];
if (a[1]==a[3]) b[z]=a[1];
if (a[1]==a[4]) b[z]=a[1];
if (a[1]==a[5]) b[z]=a[1];
if (a[2]==a[3]) b[z]=a[2];
if (a[2]==a[4]) b[z]=a[2];
if (a[2]==a[5]) b[z]=a[2];
if (a[3]==a[4]) b[z]=a[3];
if (a[3]==a[5]) b[z]=a[3];
if (a[4]==a[5]) b[z]=a[4];
else b[z]=0; cout << b[z];

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show us how far you have gotten, and where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: @KompjoeFriek , I've edited my first post, could you take a look, please

Comment: `a[0]==a[1]` will compare the value of `a[0]` with the value of `a[1]` as you would expect. The second part after the || `a[2]` will just check if the value in `a[2]` is not zero. You probably wanted to compare the value with `a[0]` too, that would make it `a[0] == a[2]` and so on.

Comment: Check out the edited code. I've tried to fix it, but I still don't know what to do.

Comment: Lots of idea's, but just telling you the answer won't make you understand it or learn from it. With all these if's you do all the comparisons you need to find the duplicates, but you loop over them 6 times. The loop in itself is a good idea if you don't want to write all those if's. But you have done both.

Comment: I think a efficient way and much readable way would be, if you would sort the array and traverse it after for duplicates. You could also 2 for-loops where you iterate over the whole array for every index and count if there are duplicates, another way would be ...
as @KompjoeFriek said there are many ways to solve it :)

Comment: So it makes no sense for me.. I still can't reach the final result :(

Comment: EDIT: I get it now, I removed the loop, so I left only if's to do their comparisons. But now I see another issue - if I enter " 1,1,2,2,3,4 ", the output array shows only the last repeated number - "2". I want it to show all of repeated numbers - in this case "1" and "2".

Comment: That is because you store only one value, the last one :-) When you are done with all the comparisons for `a[0]`, you know if this is a duplicate value or not. Store that information! Same goes for when you are done with all the comparisons for `a[1]` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you a better understanding of how to solve this, i'll try to show you what is going on via an example.

Lets say you have just entered the 6 numbers you request via `cin`, and your `a[]` variable now looks like this in memory:

```
a[] = { 5, 2, 6, 2, 1, 6 };
```

The duplicates here are 2 and the 6. (pretty obvious for us humans) :-)

You start to compare the first 2 values in memory: `a[0]==a[1]`, then the first with the third: `a[0]==a[2]` and so on. If one of these match, you know the value of `a[0]` has at least one duplicate in memory.
Whenever that happens, you would like to do something that that information. Store it somewhere (like your `b[]` array) or just output it directly with `cout << a[0]`.

You are now finished with checking `a[0]` and can continue with `a[1]` in the same manor, except you do not have to compare with `a[0]` because you did that in the previous step. Looking at your code, it seems you already understand that you can skip that.

Lets say you really need to store the duplicates. It would help to keep track of how many duplicates you have found.

Pseudo code:

```
duplicates = 0;
if (a[0] has a duplicate) { b[duplicates] = a[0]; duplicates++; }
if (a[1] has a duplicate) { b[duplicates] = a[1]; duplicates++; }
// etc...
```

"has a duplicate" would be like the code you had earlier, like: `a[0]==a[1] || a[0]==a[2] || a[0]==[3]` and so on.

In your example you have just 6 values, so it is not much work to write all the compare statements yourself. If you needed to do this with many more numbers, it would take you ages to write it, and is prone to little mistakes like typo's. Using a for loop would work for few and many numbers:

Pseude code:

```
duplicates = 0;
for (z = 0 to 6) {
    for (y = z+1 to 6) {
       if (a[z]==a[y]) {
           b[duplicates] = a[z];
           duplicates++;
           break; // We know it is a duplicate, continue with the next value
       }
    }
}
```

But even this is not perfect. If one number occurs more than 2 times in memory, this will store the same duplicate value multiple times.